# Extensible DB editor

Tags: mysql, database, editor

I'm using MySQL.

In my DB there are several tables, containing fields with data, serialized in custom binary format. (Actually, these fields contain lists of fixed-format records, like a "sub-table".)

I need a tool to be able to edit those fields by hand while my own fancy data administration UI is still in development.

I wonder, if there is a DB viewer/editor (like PHPMyAdmin or Sequel Pro or whatever) which I would be able to easily extend to deserialize that extra data?

Note that the [de]serialization library is in plain C and I do not want to spend much time rewriting it in another language. (I would better spend that time on that data administration UI.)

Any clues?

P.S. I need the editor to work on OS X or Ubuntu (Wine is fine) or be web-based.

Answer (score 0):

Sequel Pro is open source, so you can probably get the sources and hack your code in there.

[Get it here](http://code.google.com/p/sequel-pro/).

Comment: Thanks, but without "official" "hacking" API, I'm afraid, I'll spend too much time trying to make it work... In this case it looks that I'll finish my administration UI faster.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Java app http://www.isqlviewer.com/ . You could load your C library in that using JNI. I've used iSQLviewer a lot with various databases and the download comes with code, but I can't say I've ever looked at the code!